# What does sort -b do?

Tags: pipe, sort, man, output

I have some text files where I wanted to filter some things just to practice some Linux commands.

I tried to use `sort`. The problem is that I don't see a difference with `sort -b`.

I tried the following commands:

- `cat text.txt | sort`
- `cat text.txt | sort -b`

I didn't notice any difference between both outputs. Maybe I don't really understand what ***leading blanks*** mean. Can someone explain me what does it mean? Also, it could help me if you can give me an example of text where `-b` does affect the filtering of `sort`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you see a difference or not probably depends on your locale (specifically, `LC_COLLATE`) i.e. whether space characters come before or after alphabetic characters in the collation order.

For example,

```
$ cat fileb
 xyz
  pqr
abc
jkl
```

in my default locale sorts alphabetically regardless of the `-b` switch; however

```
$ LC_COLLATE="C" sort fileb
  pqr
 xyz
abc
jkl
```

whereas

```
$ LC_COLLATE="C" sort -b fileb
abc
jkl
  pqr
 xyz
```

Comment: What is my *locale* and `LC_COLLATE`?

Comment: @PichiWuana you should be able to get a list of variables describing your current locale simply by typing `locale` at the command prompt.See also `man locale`.

Comment: Ooh... I get it. In my case it's written `LC_COLLATE ="en_US.UTF-8"`. Could you explain how does `-b` work for my case?